# Stop Cluster Group without PowerShell Module and WinRM

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

We have a requirement in our team to use a PowerShell command to stop the Cluster Group without using the FailoverClusters Module or any module.

Also, the requirement is not to use WinRM/Port 5985. I am looking for a command that would work on Port 135 for remoting.

Is there any alternate command for this?

Help would be appreciated!